# Does Kundlini power chakra exist?

Tags: yoga, meditation, om

I have heard about Kundlini powers but nobody talks about these powers on a public platform nor have I ever heard about these powers by any religious guru or Yogi. I am curious to know if Kundlini Powers really exist Or is it a part of Yoga.

Comment: Read Patanjali's Yoga Aphorisms.

Comment: thanking you. I found many interested information by reading this book. I referred many other blogs and youtube also.

Answer (score 1):

Namaste

All the seven chakras in human body are of spiritual awakening, each endowed with certain siddhis and these siddhis are spiritual siddhis come naturally with each awakened chakra automatically 
These chakras give power to the individual to see what is generally unseeable. 
i.e. ability to see beyond four concrete walls, through divine X-ray eyes, knowledge of future happenings.

To a person holding knife or gun may be powerful.  However, the power in spirituality is to see things beyond the capability of normal human being